# Wounded Pigeon in my balcony

Tags: ornithology

There is a, probably wounded, pigeon (common rock pigeon) in my balcony. It is dark right now and thus, I have very little idea about its condition. But it seems it is finding it difficult to fly/move its wings because when I approached the balcony door, it 'walked' towards the farther end of the balcony while flapping its wings very slowly.

What is the right way to handle the bird and what is the best thing I can do for him/her?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this question seems like it might be a better fit for [Pets.SE], but please do **not** crosspost, instead first check that site for similar questions and then, request migration if you don't find an answer. If you do find an answer please delete your question from this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Call the RSPCA or whatever animal rescue is active in your country and neighborhood.

Comment: More likely to be suffering from disease, old age, or poison. Providing food and water would probably be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a cat carrier then trying to intice it inside with some food would be a good idea. Try to contact your local wildlife vet for information on whether they would be willing to treat the animal. If you think it may be injured then I wouldn't reccomened handling the bird as you may hurt it further, but if you do need to then handle it by placing both hands over the wings in order to pick it up (https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/advice/how-you-can-help-birds/injured-and-baby-birds/if-you-find-an-injured-bird/) . In addition the bird could have gotten used to its injury and learned to live with it so you could monitor it for a bit and see how it's getting on. Hope it turns out alright.
If you live in the UK here is some advice from the RSPB: [https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/advice/how-you-can-help-birds/injured-and-baby-birds/sick-and-injured-birds-faqs/#:~:text=For%20most%20injured%20birds%2C%20place,how%20you%20can%20help%20it](https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/advice/how-you-can-help-birds/injured-and-baby-birds/sick-and-injured-birds-faqs/#:%7E:text=For%20most%20injured%20birds%2C%20place,how%20you%20can%20help%20it).

Comment: Well, I don't have a cat carrier. Will it be wise to let it remain there till the morning?

Comment: It'd be a good idea to wait until the morning to see how the bird is doing. If it's still in bad condition then I'd advise calling a wildlife vet, otherwise the animal will likely get used to its injury or, unfortunately, pass away

Comment: When I checked in the morning, it had already flown away. Thank you for your help:)

Comment: I hope it'll be alright. No problem!